# Reliable IMUs for ROS

Tags: imu, ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm having problems in finding reliable IMU's in ROS. So far, I have tried the UM7 and the myAHRS+ with no luck. The first one, keeps resetting its magnetic reference and the second one works well but the x axis is pointing to the north ( x-north, y-west, z-up convention ) instead to the east ( ROS convention x-east, y-north, z-up convention ).

Does anybody know one that works out of the box?

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291841/reliable-imus-for-ros/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2018-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2018-05-22**:\

> the second one works well but the x axis is pointing to the north ( x-north, y-west, z-up convention ) instead to the east ( ROS convention x-east, y-north, z-up convention )

This is just convention and can be fixed simply by rotating the outputs to correspond with the ROS expectations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out razor IMUs: http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof

I've worked with them and with the ROS package the setup is easy and it works flawlessly with this one:
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10736

But as you see that has been retired, when I bought it I got the https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14001
and there are some PRs on the page of the razor_imu_9dof to make it work with the M0.

Note the video from `razor_imu_9dof`:
https://youtu.be/5FALgpOlgvw

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2018-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2018-05-22**:
Great! Thanks!

When you refer to the page of the razor_imu_9dof, are you talking about this webpage: http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof?

What does PR stand for?

Best,

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-05-23**:
PR = Pull Request, sorry. And when I said the page I refer to the github repo, from what I've seen so far there is a fork with the code for the M0 so you are good to go:
https://github.com/KristofRobot/razor_imu_9dof

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2018-07-03**:
@bpinaya did you ever run into this problem? https://github.com/KristofRobot/razor_imu_9dof/issues/41

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-07-04**:
Not really, but from what I see it's due to the config file: https://github.com/KristofRobot/razor_imu_9dof/search?q=cfg&unscoped_q=cfg
Maybe an old branch? I'll give it a look in the weekend, but when I used it it was straight forward.

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2018-07-04**:
I forgot to catkin_make to generate the files for the dynamic reconfigure and now it works.

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-07-05**:
hehehe no problem, it's always better to remove /devel and /build and catkin_make again.
If you liked my answer please accept it ;)

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-08**:
@andrestoga I am having troubles with the razor IMU, I am using https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10736 with an arduino mega. Can you provide some details about your setup? thank you

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2018-07-09**:
@aarontan please ask it in another thread and share the link of your question in the comments so, I can help you out. Also, you can post your issue here https://github.com/KristofRobot/razor_imu_9dof/issues